# countdown timer by `RxSwift`

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I need a thirty-second time counter with `RxSwift`.
This is a duplicate question but there is no clear answer to the questions

Comment: Not enough information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Better approach for existing answer.

```
let countDown = 15 // 15 seconds 
Observable<Int>.timer(.seconds(0), period: .seconds(1), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .take(countDown+1)
        .subscribe(onNext: { timePassed in
            let count = self.countDown - timePassed
            print(count)

        }, onCompleted: {
            print("count down complete")
        })
```

Comment: Why +1 in `take()`?

Comment: @Skoua for the observable to complete including 0.

Answer (score 10):

This is an even cleaner solution in my opinion (Swift 5.3). The `onNext` closure receives the time remaining so there is no need to perform a calculation. This also makes it easier to use the `takeUntil` operator to terminate the subscription when the value is equal to `0`.

```swift
let countdown = 30
Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(1), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .map { countdown - $0 }
    .takeUntil(.inclusive, predicate: { $0 == 0 })
    .subscribe(onNext: { value in
        print(value)
    }, onCompleted: {
        print("completed")
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 2):

With 5.0 version of RxSwift you can do:

```
    Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(30), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).bind { timePassed in

    }.disposed(by: yourDisposeBag)
```

Comment: This will always emit per 30 seconds if you don't kill it.