# RxSwift Countdown time up to 0.1 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I get the topic but it still countdown the time to second. I want to count down timer up to 0.1s How can i solve that?
The code i follow:
[countdown timer by `RxSwift`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047235/countdown-timer-by-rxswift)

Thanks every one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.milliseconds(100)` instead of `.seconds(1)`

Comment: This answer is correct. Thanks my friend